# H264 encoded MKV videos freeze whole computer/Windows 7 with VLC and Media Player Classic

Tags: windows-7, freeze, vlc-media-player, media-player-classic

I have some videos encoded as H264 in MKV containers. When skipping too much in VLC or Media Player Classic the media players will either crash outright or the whole system will lock up, on occasion a blue screen but most of the time it'll sit there (and no, I've tried CTRL+ALT+DEL). When coming out of standby putting the video in to full screen in MPC (which does *not* actually *play/resume* the video) made the system blue screen.

I really don't want to have to spend hours reinstalling Windows 7 yet again for another technicality. What can I do to fix the H264 codec? The MKV files are unrelated to each other so it's not a single poorly encoded file.

Comment: Any updated VLC or video drivers available?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have the latest versions of both VLC and MPC-HC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Try Media Player Classic - Home Cinema [MPC-HC] from http://mpc-hc.org/ or SourceForge. If I am not mistaken, MPC-HC continues development where MPC left off.
2. Download K-Lite Codec Pack from a trusted source , e.g. http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/k_lite_codec_pack_full.html
   [this may be overkill].

Comment: Still getting crashes though less frequently...eh.